Using JMeter for Parallel API Testing with Varying Request Rates
I am working on a project and one of the things I have to do is to test the API.
So they give me 5 different Endpoints to test.
Each one has its own request per seconds which has to be sent.
Example:
/endpoint1 has to be tested for one minute
and the amount of requests has to be 250 in total.
It will be separated throughout the one minute randomly.
/endpoint2 has to be tested for one minute
and the amount of requests has to be 159 in total.
It will be separated throughout the one minute randomly.
Etc.
At the end I have to end up with a graph showing each of those requests and how they preformed.
All of that requests have to run in parallel.
I am using now JMeter and don`t know how to get that constant time to work and how i even can make all those request and tests run parallel.
I tried using the parallel plugin but did not work.
Can i do all of that in JMeter?

Yes, you can do that with JMeter.
What I suggest, is to use 2 different Open Model Thread Groups, each with one child Sampler underneath them (HTTP Request Sampler in your case, but can be any type of sampler, it should work the same - I used the Dummy sampler just for testing out the scenario you mentioned).
Configure them as such:
Open Model Thread group 1 Schedule setup: rate(250/min) random_arrivals(1 min)
Open Model Thread group 2 Schedule setup: rate(159/min) random_arrivals(1 min)

This setup should ensure that the target defined rate of Sampler executions is achieved within 1 minute and the 2 samplers will execute concurrently, which is what I suppose you meant by "All of that requests have to run in parallel".
Note: make sure that the checkbox Run Thread Groups consecutively (i.e. run groups one at a time) is unchecked at the level of the JMeter Test Plan.
Then you can run the test and use JMeter Listeners to check the results.


Once you are happy with the outcome, you can run the test in CLI mode, generate a .jtl results file and build the JMeter Dashboard Report based on it.

Thank you soo muchh that sounds so helpfull could we maybe add on discord just to show you what i did?
and u just tell me if that is right or not?

When i run it as you said i get that i have 0 running threads ?? why that?

You are welcome. I don't know why you are encountering this behavior but you can try to mimic my setup and see if it works exactly as I tested it and then see the difference in your setup. Anyway, that seems to be another, different problem. You can create another post where you describe your specific setup and the problem you are encountering.

it works but i get Response code:Non HTTP response code: java.net.SocketException
after the tests is done
do you know why??

I can't tell, given the limited information on hand, the error is too broad. I think that you got the answers to your question in this post. I suggest you mark an answer as a solution and open a new post describing your current setup and encountered problem. This way the community might be able to better help you.

You need to have different Thread Groups to fire requests at different throughput values.
If you need to limit the number of request to the specified amount per minute/second/hour/whatever consider using JMeter Timers, the suitable ones are:

Constant Throughput Timer
Precise Throughput Timer
Throughput Shaping Timer

The latter one in combination with Concurrency Thread Group is capable of starting new threads if current amount is not enough in order to reach/maintain the target requests rate.
